# Matlab: I want to sum count data when multiple counts occur on the same day

Tags: matlab, indexing, sum

I have a vector of days when an organism completes development, as well as the corresponding numbers of organisms completing development per day. The organisms all start development on different days, however organisms of different ages can complete development on the same day.eg.

Completion_day
22
23
23
23
24

Numbers completed
124
12 
345
7  
231

My issue is how to sum all of the organisms that complete on the same day. It is not a problem when there are only two consecutive completion days that are the same: I just add 'numbers_completed(i) to numbers_completed(i-1)'. However, if three groups of organisms complete on the same day (eg. day 23 above), the sum of the second and third 'day' overwrites the sum of the first two days. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to add the "Numbers Completed" that correspond to day 23 (so the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th entries), you can use the `find` function to index where in the "Completion day" vector they occur and then tell MATLAB to add those entries of the "Numbers completed" vector.

I implemented this as:
`completion_day = [ 22 23 23 23 24]; % defining your variables

numbers_completed = [ 124 12 345 7 231]; % defining your variables

idx = find(completion_day == 23); % find the location of completion day 23

sum(numbers_completed(idx)) % return the sum of those 3 numbers`

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the `find` and just use logical indexing as long as your vectors are the same size.  This is shorter code, and probably faster.

`completionDay = [22 23 23 23 24];

numbersCompleted = [124 12 345 7 231];

sumCompleted = sum(numbersCompleted(completionDay == 23));`

You can loop over the unique completion days with the following and get the total created each day
`uniqueDays = unique(completionDays);

for i=1:length(uniqueDays)

sumCompleted(i) = sum(numbersCompleted(completionDay == uniqueDays(i)));

end`

Comment: I like that 'unique' function. There is one issue that keeps popping up with these options however. The completion day is only calculated on each 'outside loop'. ie: there is an innermost hour loop, an outer 'day' loop and then a further 'k' loop outside in which everything is checked.eg. whether completion has been reached or not. As a result, the program cannot check all at once whether or not the completion days are repeating. It can only check each 'time around' to see if the new day is the same as what was in the vector on the day before. Thanks for your help